# Where is the config file for Momodora Reverie Under the Moonlight

Tags: steam

I have the slowdown issue with this game that require vsync to be disabled which is done by modifying the config file

This is supposed to be where the config file is: https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Momodora:_Reverie_Under_the_Moonlight#Configuration_file.28s.29_location

Here is where the game files are on my computer

```
/home/me/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Momodora RUtM/
```

I see no config.ini anywhere

Comment: keep in mind that [Momodora: Reverie Under The Moonlight](https://store.steampowered.com/app/428550/Momodora_Reverie_Under_The_Moonlight/) (than you linked to) and [Momodora 2](https://rdein.itch.io/momodora-ii) (that you tagged) are not the same game in which i am quite sure the latter isn't on steam as such would not make sense point to anything steam related

Comment: I just untagged it

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if the page you linked was updated since, but it gives the configuration path on Linux:

`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/MomodoraRUtM/config.ini`

which most likely is

`~/.config/MomodoraRUtM/config.ini`

I just fixed my 48 FPS -> 60 FPS by disabling vsync there (although I did it on Windows), it works great!